# OCaml's rectype inference

Tags: ocaml

While playing with `-rectypes` option of OCaml at some point I'm just lost.

This expression is pretty much typable:

```
# fun x -> x x;;
- : ('a -> 'b as 'a) -> 'b = <fun>
```

But here OCaml fell in infinite loop:

```
# (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x);;
  C-c C-cInterrupted.
```

Ok, I can understand, recursive type system is a quite difficult thing. But first of all, I really want to know the type of this expression and does it typable at all, and secondly, in this context, I don't understand how OCaml still can type this:

```
# fun _ -> (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x);;
- : 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

So, can someone elaborate a bit on this topic?

Comment: OCaml doesn't just typecheck the terms that you give to the toplevel, it also executes them. The infinite loop here is in the execution.

Comment: @gsg ok, and so the type is `'a`, am I right?

Comment: Yep. Probably the easiest way to find the types of diverging terms is to wrap them in `lazy`, and ignore the `lazy_t` part of the resulting type.

Comment: On emacs+merlin, C-c C-t is incredibly useful (though I don't know how well merlin handles rectype).

Comment: Also, on a side-note. It is strongly unadvised to use `-rectypes` in production code unless you are *very* familiar with the typing system.

Comment: @PatJ yep, I know, like I said, it was just for fun

Comment: This looks exactly like the Y combinator BTW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first try to evaluate your expression.

```
# (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x);;
# let x = (fun x -> x x) in x x;; (* applying the function on the left *)
# (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x);; (* inlining the let-binding *)
(* We came back to our original state, infinite loop *)
```

So the infinite loop doesn't come from the typing system, but from the semantics of the expression you gave it to.

You can get the type of an expression without evaluating it using `ocamlc -i`

```
$ echo 'let x = (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x)' > rectypes.ml
$ ocamlc -i -rectypes rectypes.ml                                                                                                                                                                                                           
val x : 'a
```

So here it is, you created a value of type `'a` (which usually means "this expression never returns").

Note that you can do the same kind of trick without using rectypes:

```
# let x =
   let rec f () = f () in
   f ();;
```

As you can understand now, your last bit of code takes any argument and never returns, hence the `'a -> 'b` type.